# Why isn't this callback resolving properly in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".links a").click(function(e){
            var toLoad = "products.html #" + this.id;
            $('#block').fadeTo('fast',0,loadContent);

            function loadContent() {  
                    $('#block').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())  
                }  
            function showNewContent() {  
                    $('#block').fadeTo('slow',100);  
                }
            e.preventDefault();
        });

    });
```

The idea is:

- click on a link to trigger (check!)
- the "block" div fades to 0 (check!)
- the content is switched out (check!)
- the "block" div fades back 100 **(whoops!)**

The behavior I see is that the div fades out, then pops back with new content as soon as the fadeOut is completed.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: `.load(... showNewContent())` should be `.load(... showNewContent)` (note the missing brackets).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
function loadContent() {
  $('#block').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())  
}
```

to

```
function loadContent() {
  $('#block').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent)  
}
```

To explain: you're *calling* the function immediately (and passing its non-existent return as to `load()`) whereas you want to pass the *function* (rather than what it returns) as the callback.

**Note:** also, [`fadeTo()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeTo) states:

> The opacity to fade to (a number from
>   0 to 1).

so you should probably change:

```
function showNewContent() {  
  $('#block').fadeTo('slow',100);  
}
```

to

```
function showNewContent() {  
  $('#block').fadeTo('slow', 1);  
}
```

Comment: This still causes it to pop directly back. Let me put it live to demo...

Also, you're 2 for 2 tonight in answering my questions. Thanks for taking a front row seat to my Sunday night jQuery self-tutorial.

Comment: You solved the bigger of two errors. (The other being that opacity is 0-1, not 0-100. It WAS fading in, but went from 0-1 (on its way to 100) VERY quickly)